# Split eigenvalue tag into eigenvalues and eigenfunctions

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently there are 131 questions with the tag `eigenvalues`. This includes both questions around the finding of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix as well as of a differential operator (and associated eigenfunctions).

As someone who is interested in questions of the latter type but not of the former, I'd like to split the tag into the two parts. I'd suggest `eigenvalues` and `eigenfunctions` personally, but open to suggestions (or telling that the tag shouldn't be split).

Comment: 131 questions is not very many, I believe, and that number can be reduced to 90 by excluding questions also tagged as `[differential-equations]`.  I reasonable question, though (+1).

Comment: Yes, I guess that all those which are tagged as both `[eigenvalues]` and `[differential-equations]` are what I'm interested in.

Comment: @KraZug which means you don't really need a separate tag :-), do you?

Comment: @Kuba, well, is there a way to watch for the intersection of two tags?

Comment: I don't think so but I also don't think it is a reason for a new tag. Otoh I am just commenting here and will wait for more input from people interested in this topic more than me.